# Nuget trying to find package for which DLL is already present inside NUPKG

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

**EDIT: Completely rewrote the question to make it clearer.**

**Scenario Setup:**

- Two projects inside one Visual Studio solution: ProjectA & ProjectB.
- ProjectA has a project reference to ProjectB.
- ProjectA is supposed to have a Nuget package which can be consumed by external project.
- ProjectB is NOT supposed to have a Nuget package, so it's DLL is made present inside ProjectA's Nuget package.
- Manually verified: ProjectB's DLL is present inside the Nuget package of ProjectA - it's inside the `\lib\netcoreapp3.1` folder.

**Problem:**

- I have a third external project called ProjectC, which is supposed to consume ProjectA's Nuget package.
- In ProjectC, I'm trying to install ProjectA's Nuget package, but when I do this, I get the following error:

```
Unable to find package Com.Company.ProjectB. No packages exist with this id in source(s): <my nuget package sources mentioned here>
```

I'm assuming Visual Studio sees ProjectA's dependency on ProjectB, and so is trying to find a Nuget package for ProjectB, **even though ProjectB's DLL is already present inside ProjectA's Nuget package**.

**Anyone know how to resolve this ? How can I make Visual Studio find ProjectB's DLL from inside ProjectA's Nuget package ???**

Here's the csproj file of ProjectA:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <AssemblyName>Com.Company.ProjectA</AssemblyName>
        <RootNamespace>Com.Company.ProjectA</RootNamespace>
        <Version>0.1.0</Version>
        <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);CopyProjectReferencesToPackage</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target DependsOnTargets="ResolveReferences" Name="CopyProjectReferencesToPackage">
        <ItemGroup>
            <BuildOutputInPackage Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths-&gt;WithMetadataValue('ReferenceSourceTarget', 'ProjectReference'))" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Common\Com.Company.ProjectB.csproj">
            <ReferenceOutputAssembly>true</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
            <IncludeAssets>Com.Company.ProjectB.dll</IncludeAssets>
        </ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Here's the contents of ProjectA's Nuget package:

```
|   Com.Company.ProjectA.nuspec
|   [Content_Types].xml
|
+---content
|       concrt140.dll
|       ... a bunch of other framework related DLLs
|
+---contentFiles
|   \---any
|       \---netcoreapp3.1
|               concrt140.dll
|               ... a bunch of other framework related DLLs
|
+---lib
|   \---netcoreapp3.1
|           Com.Company.ProjectA.dll
|           Com.Company.ProjectB.dll <----- ProjectB's DLL is included !!!
|
+---package
|   \---services
|       \---metadata
|           \---core-properties
|                   d1d5fadbf7a949e68ea0c8ab95e9d49e.psmdcp
|
\---_rels
        .rels
```

Comment: I used the technique mentioned here to include the DLL of the referenced project inside the nuget package, in case it matters: https://yer.ac/blog/2019/09/05/dotnet-pack-project-reference-and-nuget-dependency/

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you could provide a complete example. (At the moment we don't know what any of the project files look like, for a start...)

Comment: I rewrote the whole question and also added more details. Please let me know if anything is still missing or unclear.

Comment: Would be a lot clearer if you referred to "ProjectA" as "PackageA".